# Mass Emailing, best practices

Tags: c#, email, mail-server, massmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid being blocked by web mail companies for mass/bulk emailing ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162149/avoid-being-blocked-by-web-mail-companies-for-mass-bulk-emailing)

Hi All,

Actually, we need to send a thousands of email for a customer that we work and we have to build that system inhouse because of security reasons. So I cannot use external mailing tools.

After some research about the topic, I came up with that I can send the mails to a local mail server that I manage. This can be probably hmail server I guess?

Another aspect is pickup directory, i found out that it can be used to look at messages on fileserver.

What can be the other best practices I should now?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the security reasons: you're about to blast the emails out to the internet, why does it matter whether that happens before or after they're 'sent'? If it's for an intranet application then you just need to send the mails to the internal mail server.

Comment: Hi Chris, I read about that topic, but i am so new to this subject and appreciate any other things i have to know

Comment: I strongly suggest that you reconsider the in-house restriction due to security. It's very difficult to do a mass mailing these days and not get blocked by some servers because you look like a spammer. Companies like MailChimp are very good at making sure that things get through, and it's very likely that their security precautions are better than yours or any other small scale data center.  See http://www.mailchimp.com/about/security/ for an example.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would set up my own web server, configure it for outbound messages throttling (so you won't send 5k e-mails to the same recipient [e.g. Hotmail] at the same time and get blacklisted) and pass the messages to it (as you like, since it's in your own network you shouldn't incour in performance issues, just go with SMTP connection and you should be fine).

Be sure of the addresses you're writing though, because you can get reported for spamming if the recipients did not authorized your client to use their address and report you, and *your* IP address would be blacklisted.

And make sure your mail server is properly configured (FQDN, reverse DNS, SPF and such) so you maximixe the chance of your messages to be delivered.