# Django mass mailing for newsletter/invitation

Tags: django, email, spam-prevention, massmail

I try to send newsletter mail to all my subscribers in Django but I couldn't decide what is the best way to do this in Django.

Firstly, I made list of 5 email addresses and send them in a schedule (like 5 minutes delay)
However, because I add them to `to` part of the mail anyone who recieves the mail can see the other 4 people's mail addresses. 
Secondly, I put only one email address as `to`, but this time I need to decrease the delay time (like 1 minute delay) and it may cause to spamming problem.
Thirdly, I consider that adding 5 mail addresses to `bcc` part but at this time I couldn't realize what should be the `to` part of the email.

Waht is the best way to do such mass mailing by avoiding being blacklisted ?

Thanks

Comment: Check out the answers for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162149/avoid-being-blocked-by-web-mail-companies-for-mass-bulk-emailing): I think your question doesn't differ from it. Your mailing problem has little to do with Django, methinks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what your looking for [**send_mass_mail()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/?from=olddocs#send-mass-mail)